# Laptop setting date to random time upon battery dying

Tags: chromebook, date

The title says it all.

Whenever my laptop dies, it just sets the time to something wayyy ahead of what we're at, like June 28th, 2184 at 4:02 AM.

Any fix for this or is my laptop just screwed?

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS off of a Lenovo N21 Chromebook.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need a new CMOS battery (one of the little button batteries that get tucked away somewhere). Generally, check with the manufacturer for location/disassembly to get to the battery.  It may be just under a removable panel on the bottom, or require extensive disassembly.  See https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-C-E-K-M-N-and-V-Series/cmos-battery/td-p/253591  for suggestions for video and manuals.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Most probably the CMOS battery is dead, and the easiest way to correct this problem is by installing a new one. The price of CMOS battery is about 5-10 INR in India, I don't know what country you're in but 1 USD = 68INR so I assume you got a idea.

Solution 2 : Don't want to open up your laptop or replace your CMOS? 
The simplest solution is to keep your time Synchronized with Ubuntu servers, so whenever you boot your system, time is automatically fixed according to your time zone. 
Here's a guide on how to: 
https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/26921/sync-the-clock-with-internet-time-servers-in-ubuntu-10.04/